# public readonly baseUrl = environment.BaseUrl;

Tags: angular16

`` error TS2339: Property 'BaseUrl' do`es not exist on type '{}'. ``

`12   public readonly baseUrl = environment.BaseUrl;`

environment.ts

`export const environment = {`
`production: false,`
``` BaseUrl:'``http://localhost:63955/``' ```
`};`

environmentdevelopment.ts

`` export const environment = {};` ``

AuthService.ts

`export class AuthService {`

`public readonly baseUrl = environment.BaseUrl;`
`constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

`authUser(user: UserForLogin) {`
`return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/User/Login', user);`
`}`

`registerUser(user: UserForRegister) {your text`
`return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/User/login', user);`
`}`
`}`

I get this error when I call my baseurl that I defined in my enviroment.ts file in a service class.